# I need help formatting this algorithm in a way that will be accepted on Math SE

Tags: algorithms

I have the following algorithm that I would like to ask a question about on Math SE. I will post a picture and an attempt, but would love to find what Latex case will work. The code that generated the algorithm does not work.

```
 function KP-O-APPROXIMATE(n,c,W,V)
    Initialize L as a list of n numbers
    for i from 1 to n do 
        l_i <- 0
    end for
    repeat
       x <- 0 ; d <- 0 ;
       for i from 1 to n do 
          if l_i = 0 and w_i <= c_i then
              if v_i/w_i > d then
                   x <- 1; d <- (v_i / w_i)
              end if
          end if
        end for
        if x=\0 then 
             l_x <- 1; c <- c - w_x
        end if
    until x=0
    return L
 end function
```

Here is a picture of what the algorithm looks like

[image]

Comment: you are showing the output of latex using `algorithms` or similar package. stackexchange does not use latex but mathjax which emulates a subset of latex _math_ syntax.

Comment: I think the [math.se] folks should be fine with either a picture or a verbatim code block like you show. It doesn't have to be formatted using LaTeX. The only thing I'd change is to use `≠` instead of `=/`.